# finding out list of web urls being served by apache or weblogic

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, web-services, weblogic

Was never into web applications / middleware / but happen to took over a couple of webservers running apache and weblogic.

q1) How do i find out what are the individual web instances/services (or virtualhosts i assume) and their default URLs path ?

q2) is it possible for different webinstances/virtualhosts to be running under overlapping url path ?

e.g

- www.tomandjerry.com/tomhouse/ - web instanceA
- www.tomandjerry.com/jerryhouse/ - web instanceB

if yes, how does it roughly look like in the apache config for instance ?

Apologies if these sound absolutely dumb, but i hope some kind soul can point me in the right direction

Comment: it would be better if you show a real example of your question, as in "I have this in apache" and I'm not sure what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

1) a few ways.  Assuming that the active site config(s) are under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled you could go there and `grep` for the `DocumentRoot` directive.  Or use `apache2cts -S` which will display a summary of the running config.

2) No, not possible, because Apache serves up different content based on the hostname used to address the server.  You could have some directory somewhere aliased in or symbolically linked to both DocumentRoots so http://example1.com/directory and http://example2.com/directory could serve the same content from the same directory, much like many/most hosting providers do with phpMyAdmin and other control-panel-like scripts.